# Average of Most Recent 100 SQL Database Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT     DC_GRP.dc_grp, DC_GRPX.reqt_id,
           AVG(RESULTS.[var]) AS Average, STDEV(RESULTS.[var]) AS StdDev
FROM RESULTS INNER JOIN...
```

Currently I am pulling all of the *var* fields out of RESULTS, but I only need to get the most recent 100. How can I only call the most recent 100 within that AVG( ) call?

Comment: Could you give a more complete example? You want all rows, but only the average of the last 100? Or do you also want to limit the number of rows fetched to 100? Also, please define "most recent", I can't see an obvious time order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a column to define the most recent, you can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT     DC_GRP.dc_grp, DC_GRPX.reqt_id,
           AVG(r.[var]) AS Average, STDEV(r.[var]) AS StdDev
FROM (select top 100 * from RESULTS order by CreatedAt desc) r INNER JOIN...
```

This example assumes the name of the column is `CreatedAt`.